# Javascript Turn Array Into Json without double {}

Tags: javascript, json

I have two parallel mysql queries in node js(to get data quicker) and this is javascript code that reads from mysql database and put result into javascript object:

```
async.parallel({
    aaChannelsCount: function(cb) {
    /* GET - channels */
    pool.query("SELECT JSON_LENGTH(sort) AS channels FROM channels WHERE bouquet='[\"?\"]'",[rows[0].bouquet], function (err, rows, fields) {
    /* CHANNELS - count */
    if (rows.length) {
        data.push( {"channels": rows[0].channels, "radio": 0} );
            };
        });
    },
    aaVideoClub: function(cb) {
        /* GET - videoclub */
        pool.query("SELECT count(id) AS videoclub FROM vod", function (err, rows, fields) {
            /* VIDEOCLUB - count */
            data.push( {"videoclub": rows[0].videoclub} );
            res.json(data); 
        });
    }
    }, function(err, results) {
        if (err) { 
            /* SHOW - unauthorized */
            res.sendStatus(401);
        } else {
            res.json(data);
        }
    }
    );
```

I am getting using res.json(data) this output:

```
[{"channels":3,"radio":0},{"videoclub":2}]
```

And need to get this output:

```
{"channels":3,"radio":0, "videoclub":2}
```

I am using in code data.push to add result from mysql into js array object and then turn it into json.But i could not get desired result.

Comment: You mean you can't use dot notation to create properties to an object, but you can use it to call methods?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) for turning an array into parameters.

```js
var array = [{ channels: 3, radio: 0 }, { videoclub: 2 }],
    object = Object.assign(...array);
    
console.log(object);
```

Another solution would be, just to take an object and assign the properties directly, like instead of

```
if (rows.length) {
    data.push( {"channels": rows[0].channels, "radio": 0} );
}
```

use an object and assign directly

```
var object = {};

if (rows.length) {
    object.channels = rows[0].channels;
    object.radio = 0;
}
```

and so on.

BTW, after a block statement `{ ... }`, there is no need for a semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using

```js
let arr = [{"channels":3,"radio":0},{"videoclub":2}];

let result = {};
for(let element of arr){
    for(property in element){
        result[property] = element[property];
    }
}

console.log(result);
```